# Magento 2, Unable to save products (Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.)

Tags: magento2, product, database, error, index

I receive the error "Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log." when I try to save a product, and get the error below in the exception log.

> [2018-08-26 05:09:05] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1932 Table 'magento.catalogrule_group_website_replica'
>   doesn't exist in engine, query was: DELETE FROM
>   `catalogrule_group_website_replica` {"exception":"[object]
>   (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1932 Table 'magento.catalogrule_group_website_replica'
>   doesn't exist in engine, query was: DELETE FROM
>   `catalogrule_group_website_replica` at
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not
>   found: 1932 Table 'magento.catalogrule_group_website_replica' doesn't
>   exist in engine at
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   [] [2018-08-26 05:09:05] main.CRITICAL: Catalog rule indexing failed.
>   See details in exception log. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Catalog
>   rule indexing failed. See details in exception log. at
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Indexer/IndexBuilder.php:286)"}
>   []

Comment: did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem.
It was caused by the long list of pending cron jobs in table cron_schedule. I backed up the database then truncated table 'cron_schedule' with command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cron_schedule;
```

After this I reindex data and manually ran cron jobs with command `bin/magenot cron:run`
After this I was able to create/save products as normal. Having said that I'm expecting this error to crop back up again as haven't found the underlying issue for so many pending cron jobs yet.